# Could not retrieve data from URL

Tags: facebook, debugging

I have a lot of websites which are using the same CMS, and they are hosted in 3 seperated servers, only one of this servers has a problem with retrieving the title, description, and the image of any url, and in the FaceBook debugger I get this error: `Could not retrieve data from URL.`

From previous questions, I read that the reason may be an **HTML error**, but as I said before on other servers there is no problem using the same CMS.
You can try putting [this](http://www.shaharah.net/2010/news-10054.htm) URL for example in the debugger

Also, other websites on the same server which are using another CMS, or is just HTML pages are also not retrieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is sending an invalid Content-type string: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=**DEFAULT**` (Checked on the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.shaharah.net%2F2010%2Fnews-10054.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3))

[This article](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php) explains how to set this on your server.

Comment: Dear cpilko, Thanks for your answer, that was the problem, I have to change in the httpd.conf and in php.ini, because the default charset in the php.ini was set to "**DEFAULT**". Thanks again for your help :)